# connect visual studio and sql express on amazon EC2

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm newbie for Amazon EC2.
I'm given an assignment where I've to connect VS 2008 to Sql Express 2005.
VS and Sql Express are running on separate Amazon machine.
(I mean, I've to do 2 separate Remote Desktop Connection to access both).

I've no clue how to connect to the Sql Express.
I've been trying different options found in search on google, stackoverflow etc...
But no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a connection string (to server ec-xxxxxxx.xxx.amazon.com), your problem could be that the .Net instance (let's call it NET) and the SQL Server instance (SQL) don't have the rights to see each other.

1. Create two instances with the different security groups
2. On both groups, you'll like want to open RDP (you probably have that already as I can read)
3. On the SQL instance security group create an inbound rule for port 1433 and open it only for the security group of WEB. Otherwise, the whole world can access your SQL Server Express database. Like this, only the WEB instance can access it. You need to paste the security group id of WEB into the inbound rule for SQL to do that.

Good luck.